# Is there any graphics emulators for ubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, wine, emulation

I'm making my own linux distro based on lubuntu, and I wanted it to be used for gaming. I want to put a graphics emulator as a program that comes with it but I don't know if its possible. If not I can just put wine or something with it, which one is better, wine or a graphics emulator?

Comment: What is a graphics emulator?

Comment: If you plan to redistribute your distro, the biggest concern before even choosing this is checking out the licensing for the software you plan to include to ensure that you can even legally package it into your distro.

Comment: @MarkKirby My best guess is that the OP is referring to something like [this](http://wiredhut.blogspot.com/2011/08/3d-analyzer-graphics-card-emulator.html) Unfortunately I think this question still will come in as a matter of opinion regardless of the level of clarity we are (or are not) able to obtain..

Answer (score 2):

**Is there graphics emulators for Ubuntu?**

I believe you are trying to find a graphics benchmarking program. To the best of my knowledge there are only 3 total.

`glxgears` from the [mesa-utils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mesa-utils&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) package which you may already have installed and is available for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu in the [universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository). It looks like it has moved to the main repository for Yakkety and beyond. This isn't a great choice as the frame rate typically mirrors the refresh rate of your monitor.

A better alternative would be `glmark2` from the [package of the same name](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=glmark2&searchon=names) also is available for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu in the [universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository).

Installable with `sudo apt-get install glmark2`

This program tests frame rates by rotating a number of 3D models and the results don't appear to be in any way linked to the refresh rate of the monitor.

There's also a commercial benchmarks by [Unigine Corp](https://unigine.com/en/products/benchmarks) (which I have no affiliation with.) They do have a Pro versions for sale as well as Free Downloads that you can try out.

As I am not an attorney I won't address the question as to whether any of these would be legal to include in your distribution.

**Which is better wine or a graphics emulator?**

Since a graphics emulator would only allow testing, I would say `wine` offers more value. I would stress that this part of your question is primarily a matter of opinion.